# Category method symbols in static library aren't visible in main executable

Tags: ios, static-libraries, objective-c-category

We're converting a project to 64 bit and having some trouble with unrecognized selectors at runtime.

It's due to some category functions that are defined in a static library not being visible from the main executable.  We have the -ObjC linker flag set and I've even tried using -force_load with the static library path that has these category functions defined but no matter what they're still not found at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `-all_load` linker flag.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  There was actually a much more serious configuration issue with symbols being picked up from multiple places.  Since other research shows that this would be the proper solution had the problem been as simple as I thought it was, you obviously deserve the right answer vote.